# Create Google Calendar reminders with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-tasks-api

I am having a problem finding how to create a Google Calendar Reminder via Google Script. I am not talking about an event reminder, as in a reminder that is emailed or SMS to you before an event on your calendar. What I need, is to create reminders in the google calendar. These reminders are depicted with the finger and string with a bow. Does anyone know the [Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) class to use? I assume reminders would be in the Calendar Service, but for some reason, I can't find it.

Here is a link to the [reminders](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2016/04/reminders-come-to-google-calendar-on-the-web.html) I am talking about, they are different from the event reminders you can add to an event.

Comment: I think this yet to be added in the API, you can follow this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760283) to be updated. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible through GAS, there is no official API for Reminders at the present time. More information (including some third party workarounds) at this [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294548/how-do-i-create-a-reminder-using-google-calendar-api).

Answer (score -1):

Found these 3 reminder options in the same link ([Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/)) as provided in OP :)

- [addEmailReminder(minutesBefore)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series.html#addEmailReminder(Integer))
- [addPopupReminder(minutesBefore)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series.html#addPopupReminder(Integer))
- [addSmsReminder(minutesBefore)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series.html#addSmsReminder(Integer))

Looks like these features are available now!

Comment: These are reminders for the event, which this question is (explicitly) not about.