# How do I create a reminder using Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-calendar-api

In the regular web UI for Google Calendar, when I add an event, I can choose to make it a "reminder", rather than an "event".

I'm trying to replicate that with the Python API, but can't seem to find info on how to do that. All the documentation I'm finding pertains to reminders on events (i.e. "remind half an hour before the event"), rather than the "pure" reminders.

How does one add just a pure reminder?

[image: Pure reminder (not event reminder)]

Comment: Add your star to the [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4437&can=1&sort=-stars&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner).

Answer (score 18):

Adding [Reminders](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327) is [not currently possible.](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/)

As [Aaron suggested,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294548/how-do-i-create-a-reminder-using-google-calendar-api#comment73111459_41294548) there's an official [Feature Request that can be upvoted.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760283)

Answer (score 15):

I created a simple tool that does exactly that: [google-reminders-cli](https://github.com/jonahar/google-reminders-cli)

Answer (score 3):

I have translated Jona's https://github.com/jonahar/google-reminders-cli from Python to:

- JavaScript: https://github.com/Jinjinov/google-reminders-js
- PHP: https://github.com/Jinjinov/google-reminders-php