# How to get all Google Calendar Goals and Reminders that are marked as DONE

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-tasks-api

In **Google Calendar** it is possible to:

1.) Mark a **Goal** as "Did it":

[image: Goal]

2.) Mark a **Reminder** as "Mark as done":

[image: Reminder]

3.) Mark a **Task** as "Mark complete":

[image: Task]

I know that it is possible to use **Google Tasks API** to get a list of all **Tasks** marked as "complete" by checking the `task.status` string property and comparing it to `"completed"`:

https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks

In the **Google Calendar API**, I only found "Events" - **Goals** are never mentioned and **Reminders** are only mentioned as "email / sms / popup" reminders for the events **(which is not what I want)**.

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/

I can't find the **Google Keep API**.

### How can I get a list of all Goals and Reminders marked as "done"?

I am willing to work with anything: Google Calendar / Google Tasks / Google Keep

I would use any official or unofficial / open source API in either Javascript or Php.

I would appreciate any answer or suggestion, thank you!

Comment: Two years old but still relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294548/ In particular see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On GitHub I found a Python library for Google Reminders:

https://github.com/jonahar/google-reminders-cli

The Reminder class has a bool variable "done", which is exactly what I wanted.

That is why I ported the Python library to JavaScript and to PHP:

https://github.com/Jinjinov/google-reminders-js

https://github.com/Jinjinov/google-reminders-php

Answer (score -1):

I have checked this official reference of Google Tasks API.

https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/list

in this API, there is a request parameter for showCompleted.

you can set it to true and other will be false.

Please let me know if you will face any other issue regarding this.

Comment: Wrong! That is for Tasks, my question is for Reminders!