# Error: unsupported_response_type when using Google OAuth

Tags: javascript

I'm working on setting up an API for google reminders and using code that someone had put together on GitHub: https://github.com/Jinjinov/google-reminders-js

For more context, please view this stack overflow post: [How do I create a reminder using Google Calendar API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294548/how-do-i-create-a-reminder-using-google-calendar-api)

I've already set up the client ID and set the redirect URL:

```
var YOUR_CLIENT_ID = '646966110929-4qg0s2ll21jk81b6o8rk15jd6c1m42vn.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var YOUR_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8000';
```

But getting an error:

Error: unsupported_response_type

Please see attached image for more details
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zuAW.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="reminders"></div>

    <script src="reminders.js">
      console.log ("hello 0")
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      console.log ("hello")

      var YOUR_CLIENT_ID = '646966110929-4qg0s2ll21jk81b6o8rk15jd6c1m42vn.apps.googleusercontent.com';
      var YOUR_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8000';

      var fragmentString = location.hash.substring(1);

      // Parse query string to see if page request is coming from OAuth 2.0 server.
      var params = {};
      var regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;

      while (m = regex.exec(fragmentString)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
      }

      if (Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
        localStorage.setItem('oauth2-params', JSON.stringify(params) );
      }

      sendRequest();

      // If there's an access token, try an API request.
      // Otherwise, start OAuth 2.0 flow.
      function sendRequest() {
        var params = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oauth2-params'));

        if (params && params['access_token']) {

          list_reminders(10, params['access_token'], function (reminders) {
            if (reminders != null) {
              var innerHTML = '';
              for(var reminder of reminders) {
                innerHTML += '<p>';
                innerHTML += reminder;
                innerHTML += '</p>';
              }
              document.getElementById("reminders").innerHTML = innerHTML;
            }
            else if (reminders == null) {
              // Token invalid, so prompt for user permission.
              oauth2SignIn();
            }
          });

        }
        else {
          oauth2SignIn();
        }
      }

      console.log("hello2")

      /*
      * Create form to request access token from Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
      */
      function oauth2SignIn() {
        // Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoint for requesting an access token
        var oauth2Endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';

        // Create element to open OAuth 2.0 endpoint in new window.
        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('method', 'GET'); // Send as a GET request.
        form.setAttribute('action', oauth2Endpoint);

        // Parameters to pass to OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
        var params = {
          'client_id': YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
          'redirect_uri': YOUR_REDIRECT_URI,
          'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/reminders',
          'include_granted_scopes': 'true',
          'response_type': 'token'
        };

        // Add form parameters as hidden input values.
        for (var p in params) {
          var input = document.createElement('input');
          input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
          input.setAttribute('name', p);
          input.setAttribute('value', params[p]);
          form.appendChild(input);
        }

        // Add form to page and submit it to open the OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When Google shows you this error, what it the value of `response_type` in the URL?

Comment: can you please post your code as text? 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm getting a 400 error

Comment: Added code as text :)